# How long does a Binding last?

Tags: gurps-4e

The Binding advantage in GURPS allows a character to hold another character in place, in a way similar to being grappled by a creature with ST equal to the level of your Binding.

My problem is that the advantage seems annoyingly non-specific about exactly how long the binding lasts.  If I have a strong enough Binding, can I keep someone held forever?  It seems like that's what the advantage is implying, but it seems kind of weird that Binding would be effectively permanent, given a high enough level of Binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. That's what spiders have Binding for: they frequently do keep their prey bound for the rest of their lives!

Beware that you should have a sensible reason to take the Binding advantage. It's not just grappling, it's actually *binding* (i.e., with a web or other restraint) the target.